# How does tcpdump configure an interface it begins to capture packets from?

Tags: networking, tcpdump, ifconfig, embedded-linux

On an Arago embedded linux system, an interface would normally be able to ping other destinations on the network. However, the pings stop working when using a utility such as iperf or scp to send TCP traffic to these destinations. Addtionally, the iperf and scp works momentarily (i.e., sends data) and then the tcp traffic of the iperf and scp stops. At the same time, the ICMP traffic of the ping to the destination device stops.

When we run tcpdump on the interface, it appears to allow the sending of tcp traffic from point A to point B without an issue. How could tcpdump make it work? It feels like the double slit experiment, that the act of observing makes it behave one way and the act of not observing makes it behave another way.

In any case, it is an embedded linux environment (Arago) that has busybox installed. If anyone has an idea of how tcpdump might affect an interface its listening on, please share your understanding.

The tcpdump command I use is the following:

> tcpdump -i {interface} -w {file_name.pcapng}

NOTE: One hypothesis I had was that tcpdump puts the interface in promiscuous mode when capturing packets. However when I put it in promiscuous mode using "ifconfig {interface} promisc" without tcpdump, the data didn't go through and pings became unresponsive (i.e., the same undesired result). Are there other things that tcpdump does to the interface it sniffs?

Comment: 1) You're asking an XY question.  Understanding tcpdump may not resolve the actual problem.  2) The actual problem is unclear since you've worded it in negative terms:  *"an interface will be unable to ping outside the network"*   But what is the interface *able* to do?  What happens "inside" the network?  Have you tried `arping`?  *"the behavior was the link went down"* -- As in `/sys/class/net/<interface>/operstate` would actually indicate the link is down, or do you really mean that you couldn't get it to respond?

Comment: Let me try to explain my question in the terms you suggested.

Comment: I tried to explain the question better. To answer your specific questions. ""an interface will be unable to ping outside the network" But what is the interface able to do? What happens "inside" the network?" Its able to send tcp data traffic momentarily without tcpdump and is able to send tcp data successfully with tcpdump. The destination IP is within the same network as the interface. "Have you tried arping?" NO.

Comment: "the behavior was the link went down" -- As in /sys/class/net/<interface>/operstate would actually indicate the link is down, or do you really mean that you couldn't get it to respond? I didn't know about this file so next time I will check this and report back later. But when the undesired behavior occurs, I can still ping the interface but I can't ping destination devices that should normally be accessible from that interface. Thank you for your input.